# What is the best way to add a custom defined scheduler in RayTune?

Tags: python, hyperparameters, automl, ray-tune

I want to try some scheduler for ASA and HPO that is not implemented on RayTune so I was wondering if there is any way to do that as I could not find information about that on the documentation.